# Is it valid in objective-c to traverse object-graphs this way?

Tags: objective-c

Imagine you have a recursive object-structure like this:

```
MyComposite *c = [MyComposite compositeWithName:@"Jack"];

// add/append some children ...    

do
{
  // do something with the current composite
  ...
  // continue traversal
  c = [c child];
}while ( c );
```

Is this traversal valid in terms of memory management?

Comment: depends on allocation type of child's objects and if the parent is retained and released appropriately (@dynamic or @property ...)

Comment: the parent is a weak property (nonatomic,assign), the child is a property (nonatomic,retain)

Comment: i'm just wondering if the graph is disturbed by assigning c.child to c

Comment: It is very un-Objective-C-ish to name a getter "get…".

Comment: yes i know, but this is not the focus of the problem.

Comment: i have edited to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's fine. c is a local variable pointing to the instance of MyComposite. Reassigning another MyComposite pointer value to c does not have any effect upon the original MyComposite instance.

In reference to Yuji's  answer, you should not use a NSArray or NSSet to store a recursive data structure, your data structure is fine. NSArray and NSSet are designed for flat data sets and cannot specify any relationship between their members other than enforcing a linear ordering in the case of NSArray.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, there's nothing wrong with that. However:

1. Usually in Objective-C, you just use `NSArray` or `NSSet`, and you don't write your own linked-list class. Note that `NSArray` is not really an array in the standard sense. For example, inserting objects in the middle is not terribly slow.
2. As `WTP` says, you don't name getters `get...`. If the property name is `foo`, the getter is just named `foo` and the setter is named `setFoo:`. It's largely a convention, but some part of the Cocoa system depends on this convention. So, rename your method immediately, when you finish reading this sentence.